# Concatenating an integer to a string

Tags: c++

I am trying to save a sequence of images in visual studio 2008,all with the prefix of "Image".
the only differentiating factor should be their number.
for example if I am gonna save 10 images then the situation should be

```
i=1;
while(i<10)
{
cvSaveImage("G:/OpenCV/Results/Imagei.jpg",img2);
i++
//"i" is gonna be different every time
}
```

so I need to concatenete the integer with the string...
 looking forward to the answer...

Comment: Than your question isn't about saving a sequence of images, it's about string manipulation.

Comment: char name[50]; sprintf(name,"filename%d.jpg", 10); // check also snprintf to print at max 50 characters.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen, that's not the C++ way, but post it as an answer so the issue can be resolved.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen,this works but the cvSaveImage doesn't seem to be taking array as a path to save image:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The c++ way (pre-c++11) would be:

```
#include <sstream>
...
ostringstream convert;
convert << "G:/OpenCV/Results/Image" << i << ".jpg";
cvSaveImage(convert.str().c_str(), img2);
i++;
```

Answer (score 3):

With C++11:

```
#include <string>

string filename = "G:/OpenCV/Results/Image" + to_string(i) + ".jpg";
cvSaveImage(filename.c_str(), img2);
```

*edit*

A generic and possibly more efficient way of building strings is to use a `stringstream`:

```
ostringstream ss;

ss << "G:/OpenCV/Results/Image" << i << ".jpg";

string filename = ss.str();
cvSaveImage(filename.c_str(), img2);
```

This also works with pre-C++11 compilers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you start with `i = 10` and do `while( i < 10 )`, then your code will save only 9 items. Now to your question,

```
for( i = 1; i < 11; i++ )
{
  std::stringstream imagenum;
  imagenum << "G:/OpenCV/Results/Image" << i << ".jpg" ;
  cvSaveImage(imagenum.str().c_str(), img2) ;
}
```

Check [example_link](http://codepad.org/6u1zggRv)

Answer (score 1):

opencv comes with cv::format() [which is probably just a sprintf wrapper, but quite handy, imho]

so, your example could look like:

```
cv::imwrite( cv::format( "G:/OpenCV/Results/Image%d.jpg", i ), img );
```

or, if you insist on using the outdated 1.0 api, :

```
cvSaveImage( cv::format( "G:/OpenCV/Results/Image%d.jpg", i ).c_str(), img );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string imgname="./Image_";
char cbuff[20];
sprintf (cbuff, "%03d", i);
imgname.append(cbuff);
imgname.append(".jpg");
```

Output:

```
./Image_001.jpg
./Image_002.jpg
./Image_010.jpg etc.
```